# How can I deal with a coworker who only yells?

Tags: communication, work-environment, colleagues

This isn't a case of workplace aggression, just some guy I work with who only yells to communicate. He's not mad ever, he just only talks in a super loud voice. Everyone tells him to talk quieter and he doesn't. It gives me a headache when he comes over to my desk and starts yelling at me.

*What are some things I can do to mitigate this?*

Comment: Try to speak with same volume as he does to you and see how he reacts.

Comment: Also does he have some medical condition?

Comment: is it your manager? Do you have a manager? Have you discussed this issue with your manager? They are responsible in part for your performance, it suffers if the workplace is uncomfortable

Comment: @shtummie you can try to speak with same volume for some time see the reaction of that person. If no reaction came from him better to inform him personally and ask him for keep voice low.

Comment: I would just keep repeating to lower his voice, and if that doesn't work I'd ask the person to email or slack me.

Answer (score 5):

"Inside voice, please".

Or pull him aside and have an honest discussion.   Say "You know....seriously...you really don't have to use that much volume".

Or, start talking about a private conversation you overheard him have with a co-worker from across the room.

Answer (score 5):

You need to simply ask him why he yells. He may not even realize it.  I've been told that I yell sometimes when I'm not intending to, even in normal conversation.  I have a hearing problem and some very bad tinnitus. It could be that.

Comment: +1 for the "hearing problem" part. Could be that he only is in need of a hearing aid.

Comment: The unfortunate part is that so many of us with hearing problems can't afford them and they're usually not covered by insurance (in the US)

Answer (score 0):

You're too loud. You're giving me a headache. Talk quieter or get or go somewhere else.

No reason to sugar coat. If others have been telling your coworker this and they're still too loud then they probably don't realize it's serious. Being rude will help them understand it's a real serious problem. Also, the responses above aren't actually rude enough to cause any disciplinary actions.

This is also something you can tell HR about.